# How to easily show newline with Sonata Admin Bundle list view

Tags: newline, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

How should I be able to add newlines to the list view table in the SonataAdminBundle?

I added a function to my entity like this:

```
getTest() {
    return "test 1 \n test 2";
}
```

And in my `configureListFields` function I add the field this way:

```
$listMapper->add('test', null, array('label' => 'Test'))
```

I also tried changing the type to `text`, `string` and `doctrine_orm_text`, but it doesn't help.

Using `<br />` instead of `\n` doens't help eather, because the output is translated to html entities.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more simple way:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('message', null, array(
            'template' => 'SensioPlatformBundle:Admin:AuditTrail/message.html.twig',
        ))
    //...
```

Then in your template:

```
<td>
    {{ value|nl2br }}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a possibility: Override the base_list_field.html.twig template for the text template: Add the `nl2br` filter when the block `field` is defined:

`list_text_field.html.twig`

```
<td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-{{ field_description.type }}" objectId="{{ admin.id(object) }}">
{% if
        field_description.options.identifier is defined
    and field_description.options.route is defined
    and admin.isGranted(field_description.options.route.name == 'show' ? 'VIEW' : field_description.options.route.name|upper, object)
    and admin.hasRoute(field_description.options.route.name)
%}
    <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl(field_description.options.route.name, object, field_description.options.route.parameters) }}">
        {%- block field %}{{ value|nl2br }}{% endblock -%}
    </a>
{% else %}
    {{ block('field') }}
{% endif %}
</td>
```

In your `config.yml`:

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    templates:
        types:
            list:
                text: YourBundle:Admin:list_text_field.html.twig
```

`configureListFields`

```
$listMapper->add('test', 'text', array('label' => 'Test'))
```